# Finding a Fitting Ticket-System

Tags: software-development, task-management, help-desk

long time forum stalker here - now finally with a question I think is best posted here.

Weve looked at known top ticket-systems up to now (FreshDesk, Jira, Zendesk, etc), but there are some important points that we cant find any good answers on.

From the top down: Were looking for an internal Ticket-System that is a good match for our small dev-company (>10 employees). We have a niche industry software that we have been developing alongside our customers for a good few years now. We keep our software standardised across all customers - so very little to no differentiation between them (no ugly [if (customer)] or [case customer] shenanigans).
Being so small, the guy that picks up a todo from a customer is often also the one who does the final fix-commit - we really dont need such a big software package or convoluted eldritch multilevel heirarchical do-everything package - were simply looking for a solution that can pick up some loose-ends

With that philosophy, we quickly come to...

Point 1:
Have tickets that can pertain to multiple customers at once.
In some of the systems weve looked at so far, it very much is possible - but how they do it is somewhat convoluted and sounds a bit overblown for our purposes.

Point 2:
Tickets leading to further Tickets.
As some of us have surely lived through - some "hmm, thats funny" moments lead to some pretty wild and strenuous goose chases that end in "yeah no, this algorithm is crap - we need to rewrite this".
Up to now, we havent been able to find out which systems have ... well, ticket chaining and legacy tracking, for lack of a better phrase.

Point 3:
Feature/Interaction/Version tracking.
While this could be a simply .xlsx sheet in conjuction with version numbers, Meeting summaries, etc - it would be a massive help if this could be seamlessly integrated into said ticket system on an at-a-glance basis. Things like feature/change requests, which version and features the customer has, customer-specific info or specific contact adresses etc.

Those are the main points - there are some nice-to-haves but those are just some extras. We dont want to constrain the choice of software just because Frank wants a cupholder x).
Weve also talked about building our own system with Azure PowerApps and PowerAutomation, though why reinvent the wheel, we figured

I must also admit, Im somewhat insecure about this subject - things that I would think are relatively self-evident dont seem to be things that Im finding searching this subject on the net. Who knows, maybe these things Im listing are as basic as a car having doors and theyre not worth mentioning - or we here in our isolated cave are so arse-backwards that no software on earth can help us. Im also conscious about the fact that these things are reaching into multiple domains, from bug/project-management to documentation, to document management and to helpdesk etc ... but these are all loose ends.

So ... any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Points 1 and 2, Spiceworks may be able to do it,

1. You can set rules that say when a ticket is made by (list) copy these people.. Useful for doing things like copying managers on reports' tickets.
2. You can chain tickets like this person asked this and then that, but that was a subcategory of this.

That would be at least free to try.

I am however unaware of a good ticketing AND document revision system in one package.

You *may* be able to beat redmine into both, also free to try and effortless as well, as turnkey Linux has a deployable OVA to spin it up and look in a jifffy. Since it can be customized ad infinitum, and does issue tracking, project management etc, I could see it possibly both as a ticketing system and document management being eeked out, maybe even nicely. Worth a look.

Spiceworks ticket system: https://www.spiceworks.com/free-cloud-help-desk-software/

Redmine:https://www.redmine.org/

Turnkey deployable OVA: https://www.turnkeylinux.org/redmine

Comment: What do you mean by "Spiceworks"? Please always link to the software you're recommending.

Comment: Not really getting that, like the other post for quickbooks, these are not sales pitches they are suggestions. When you simply put spiceworks into a browser, the very first PAGE is about their cloud help desk and since the question is about ticket systems, it is not exactly ambiguous? I honestly do not understand this comment?

Comment: Would it not be more appropriate to have the OP post in appropriate forms after making a suggestion what to explore "How do I in_______?" as this is not a forum FOR those software it is to get suggestions on options to explore? Not trying to be rude here, I simply do not get what you are getting at.

Comment: Firstly, 1st result in Google differs for everyone, I recommend getting familiar with how search engines work. For me it's random website without any software and I wouldn't know what to download if I was the requester here Secondly, even if it didn't, 5 different software called Spiceworks could appear during next 5 years - answers here are supposed to last. I have no idea what you find weird/unusual about adding a link to something you're referring to. https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Nothing at all unusual for adding it, and *that* argent is valid. I am quite aware of how search engines work. I will review the link.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - Weve also come across JitBit and Alsana, which are along the lines of ready-made packages. Weve also looked at Trac - which would be more in line with Redmine as a more hands-on thing.

While I understand that we will need to customize and throw out some aspects of the software we dont need (which means work), my Boss wants a works-out-of-the-box kind of thing of course, even though there really is no such thing - at least, not in a reasonable price range... Well see

Comment: There is also dude solutions helpdesk https://www.brightlysoftware.com/sites/default/files/2020-09/Help-Desk_datasheet.pdf kind of ironic once i noticed your name it clicked. We had them demo  for our maintenance dept once, was overkill for what they needed, but it looked nice at the time.

Comment: though with a quick look, it doesnt seem like theyre still servicing their help-desk software.
Still hillarious though - they would have gotten an extra ten points on my spreadsheet just for that x)

Answer (score 0):

You say you have looked at and judged against Jira, but you do not mention why you did so. I assume you got the impression that Jira is large and unwieldy, and its many features somehow would distract from daily work. My experience with it is that this is not necessarily the case. Many of its features are totally optional, and my experience with quite a few different teams using it is that most people get into it quickly enough. The default settings should be just fine for most users; one area of customization I would suggest to look into early is how to *remove* many fields you do not need in forms, to avoid clutter, but even that is rather optional, IMO/IME.

So I recommend Jira as it can do all you want:

> Point 1: Have tickets that can pertain to multiple customers at once.

There are several possible solutions for that in Jira. A ticket can have labels and components, amongst other mechanisms, and you could simply have a label or component for each customer, depending on what you deem makes sense for you.

> Point 2: Tickets leading to further Tickets.

In Jira you would use "linked" tickets for this - any two tickets can be linked, with some kind of label as well ("depends on", "blocks", "relates to" etc.).

Alternatively, you can use Sub-Tasks, which are shown as such in several places in the GUI (i.e. in a small sub-list on their parent ticket, with a special bread-crumb list in agile boards, etc.).

Thirdly, if you can plan in advance, you can use Epics, which are tickets that link to other tickets but also offer some further GUI niceties (i.e., quick filtering in the backlog, coloring, etc.).

> Point 3: Feature/Interaction/Version tracking

Yes, it has that as well. It's called "release" in Jira, and it is trivial to create a new one - you literally type its name in a field where you can specify the "fix release" of a ticket, and it will automatically create a release object for you - you do not need to enter any more data if you do not wish, and Jira forces nothing on you if you use that mechanism. You *can* then use a GUI specially for releases though, i.e. listing all tickets in the release, giving a nice overview how many are ready or unfinished etc.

You don't mention it, but Jira comes with several agile boards - i.e., Scrum and Kanban. They are optional to use as well, but if you are not opposed to some structuring, I recommend to use them. If you employ no formal agile process already, I highly suggest you start with the "Kanban" boards in Jira as they are (similarly to the "Kanban" process itself) are as lightweight as you can get, and basically just a transparent pipeline where your tickets travel from left to right, with no concept of "Sprint" or other structure.